# Passing multiple values for list

Tags: terraform

I am using lists, but I am struggling to understand how to pass more than one value in a list. For instance each VPC requires 2 subnets, one for aza and one for azb. The tfvars file has a list of all 6 subnets [“subnet1”, “subnet2”, “subnet3”, etc etc]

So I am calling three identical modules (just copied my master two additional times.) and in the area for VPC I am using:

tfvars list =
`vpc_cidr = [“10.211.128.0/27”, “10.211.128.32/27”, “10.211.128.64/27”]`

main.tf =
`environment-vpc = var.environment-vpc[0]` for vpc1
`environment-vpc = var.environment-vpc[1]` for vpc2
`environment-vpc = var.environment-vpc[2]` for vpc3

my subnets are listed as is:

tfvars =

`public_subnets_cidr = [“10.211.128.0/28”, “10.211.128.16/28”, “10.211.128.32/28”,  “10.211.128.48/28”, “10.211.128.64/28”, “10.211.128.80/28”]`

main.tf =
`public_subnets_cidr = var.public_subnets_cidr`

This is where I cannot figure out how to pass two objects in the list to the first vpc, then the next two for the second vpc and the last two for the third vpc.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the effect you want is similar to the functionality of [Terraform's `chunklist` function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/chunklist.html):

> `chunklist` splits a single list into fixed-size chunks, returning a list of lists.

Experimenting in `terraform console` we can see the effect of calling `chunklist` with your `public_subnets_cidr` value:

```
> chunklist(["10.211.128.0/28", "10.211.128.16/28", "10.211.128.32/28",  "10.211.128.48/28", "10.211.128.64/28", "10.211.128.80/28"], 2)
tolist([
  tolist([
    "10.211.128.0/28",
    "10.211.128.16/28",
  ]),
  tolist([
    "10.211.128.32/28",
    "10.211.128.48/28",
  ]),
  tolist([
    "10.211.128.64/28",
    "10.211.128.80/28",
  ]),
])
```

This creates a list of lists where the first level of lists now has the same length as your `vpc_cidr` value, and so you can use the same indices with both lists.

You can use [Local Values](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/values/locals.html) to declare a new symbol with a value you've derived locally within your module:

```
locals {
  vpc_subnet_cidrs = chunklist(var.public_subnets_cidr, 2)
}
```

With that declaration, you can couple every reference like `var.environment-vpc[1]` with a reference like `local.vpc_subnet_cidrs[1]` to get the pair of CIDR ranges belonging to that VPC.

---

Since your addresses here seem to be assigned systematically, it might also interest you to know that Terraform has [a `cidrsubnet` function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/cidrsubnet.html) which can calculate CIDR ranges dynamically from a base CIDR range. Using that, you might be able to avoid explicitly setting the subnet CIDR blocks at all, instead just computing them from the VPC cidr block:

```
> cidrsubnet("10.211.128.0/27", 1, 0)
"10.211.128.0/28"
> cidrsubnet("10.211.128.0/27", 1, 1)
"10.211.128.16/28"
```

In the above `terraform console` examples, we're asking Terraform to extend the base CIDR block `10.211.128.0/27` by one bit, creating a `/28` prefix. The first one says to fill in that extra bit with zero and the second to fill it in with one, creating the first two elements of your list of subnets.

Comment: I have never heard of chunklist until now. So its basically a nested list. Each sub-level list belonging to each vpc created. Could you do a count with this or a for_each so you dont have to create 3 vpc modules?

Comment: It should be possible to reorganize that so you could use `for_each` or `count` with it, but that seems like a different question than you originally asked so I'd suggest starting a new question page for it on Stack Overflow so I or someone else can post a full answer about it.